# Why PHP `__invoke` Not Working When Triggered from an Object Property

Tags: php

I wonder whether this is a bug or normal. Let’s say I have a class with some magical functions:

```
class Foo {
    public function __toString() {
        return '`__toString` called.';
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return '`__get(' . $key . ')` called.';
    }
    public function __invoke($x = "") {
        return '`__invoke(' . $x . ')` called.';
    }
}
```

And then create an instance in an object property like this:

```
$object = (object) [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => new Foo
];
```

Then test it:

```
echo $object->baz;
echo $object->baz->qux;
echo $object->baz('%'); // :(
```

It is broken in the last echo: `Call to undefined method stdClass::baz()`

Currently, the only solution I can do is to store the `__invoke` part in a temporary variable and then call that variable as a function like this:

```
$x = $object->baz;
echo $x('%'); // :)
```

It works fine when I instantiate the class in an array property:

```
$array = [
    'baz' => new Foo
];

echo $array['baz'];
echo $array['baz']->qux;
echo $array['baz']('%'); // :)
```

By the way, I need this ability on my object for something related to API:

```
$foo = (object) ['bar' => new MyClass];
```

- `echo $foo->bar;` → should trigger `__toString`
- `echo $foo->bar->baz;` → should trigger `__get`
- `echo $foo->bar();` → should trigger `__invoke`
- `echo $foo->bar->baz();` → should trigger `__call`

All of them should return a string.

Can this be done in PHP completely? Thanks.

Comment: interesting question, i wonder if it's php's deficiency, like suggested in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) one of the contribs said that invoking a class inside a class throws an error.

Comment: wait, actually you did not required to put it temporarily somewhere, `echo ($object->baz)('%')` works.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa What PHP version are you using? I just got an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in I:\server\www\test.php on line 22`. I am with **5.6.18**.

Comment: i'm testing with [phptester](http://phptester.net/) that uses php 7 -- sorry, can't test on my own machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by detecting the existence of an `__invoke` method inside the `__call` method of a class.

```
class MyStdClass extends stdClass {
    protected $data = [];
    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->data = $array;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
    }
    public function __call($key, $args = []) {
        if (isset($this->data[$key])) {
            $test = $this->data[$key];
            // not an object = not an instance, skip!
            if (!is_object($test)) {
                return $this->__get($key);
            }
            if (!empty($args) && get_class($test) && method_exists($test, '__invoke')) {
                // or `return $test(...$args)`
                return call_user_func([$test, '__invoke'], ...$args);
            } 
        }
        return $this->__get($key);
    }
    public function __set($key, $value = null) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return json_encode($this->data);
    }
    public function __isset($key) {}
    public function __unset($key) {}
}
```

So, instead of converting the array into object with `(object)`, here I use:

```
$object = new MyStdClass([
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => new Foo
]);
```

Answer (score 7):

No can do.

The line in question is simply ambigous, and the error message shows you how ... It is more logical to try to access the `baz()` method of your `$object` object.
That's just the context given by the parser when it sees `$object->baz()`

As already mentioned in the comments, you can remove that ambiguity, help the parser by telling it that `$object->baz` is itself an expression that needs to be executed first:

```
($object->baz)('arg');
```

PHP is also itself a program, and has to know how to execute something before executing it. If it could blindly try every possible "magic" method on every object in a `$foo->bar->baz->qux` chain, then it wouldn't be able to tell you what the error is when it is encountered - it would just silently crash.

Comment: The parenthesis syntax looks promising in the future.

Comment: Yea, it's just a shorthand for `$var = $object->baz; $var('arg');`. It doesn't work prior to PHP 7, but you should be moving to that ASAP anyway.